# Refresh a Jquery widget using javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a Jquery library called "Tags Manager (http://welldonethings.com/tags/manager/v3)" to display tags in a nice way. I'm initializing it with

```
jQuery(".tm-tag_string").tagsManager({
    output: '#field-tags'
    tagsContainer: '#cnt-field-tags'  
});
```

The tags are stored in a hidden input `#field-tags`. All works fine when the page loads and there are tags in the hidden input value. But if I set the hidden input value using javaScript:

```
$('#field-tags').val('Kenya, Uganda');
```

tagsManager does not update to show the tags. Seems like I need to refresh tagsManager but I don't know how.

I tried recalling:

```
jQuery(".tm-tag_string").tagsManager({
        output: '#field-tags'
        tagsContainer: '#cnt-field-tags'  
});
```

or

```
$(".tm-tag_string").tagsManager('refresh');
```

But nothing seems to work. Any idea?

Carlos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the documentation (http://welldonethings.com/tags/manager/v3), it looks like you will need to use the built-in method,

```
tagApi.tagsManager("pushTag", d.value);
```

So, I would try:

```
jQuery(".tm-tag_string").tagsManager({
    output: '#field-tags'
    tagsContainer: '#cnt-field-tags'
});

jQuery(".tm-tag_string").tagsManager("pushTag", 'Kenya');
jQuery(".tm-tag_string").tagsManager("pushTag", 'Uganda');
```